# In powershell, Have Out-Host with conditional statement

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to append | Out-Host with each Powershell execution.
But the response with out-host changes as below

```
>> some crap 
>> $? --> returns false

>> some crap | Out-Host
>> $? --> returns false as expected

>> $(some crap) | Out-Host
>> $? --> returns true not expected
```

I understand that the true return might be because of the subexpression that I have introduced. But I see it needed in scenarios where I have a conditional script. There simple appending Out-Host doesn't work. For example,

```
$condition = $true; if ( $condition ) {echo "The condition was true"} | Out-Host
```

The above fails that an empty pipe is not allowed
If I change it to the below, it works

```
$($condition = $true; if ( $condition ) {echo "The condition was true"} )| Out-Host
```

I basically want to append Out-Host such that my output/response of run doesn't get affected. Since Out-Host is said to be the default, there should be a way to handle it for conditional statements as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if($condition){ echo "The condition was true" | Out-Host}`

Comment: Okay, but what comes is dynamic. So cannot confirm that a conditional will come or not. Hence Just would prefer appending at the end

Comment: That's a choice you'll have to make: 1) Comply with the weird requirement to use `Out-Host` and `$?` all over the place, or 2) Write nice and maintainable code :-) The only other alternative I see is adding the `Out-Host` statements programmatically - use PowerShell's built-in parser to locate all pipeline expression and add `| Out-Host` in the right place

Comment: @SonaliGupta - from the help system >>> `$? = Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains TRUE if the last command succeeded and FALSE if it failed.` <<< so that final `Out-Host` is working correctly ... and that means the `$?` will contain `True`. [*grin*]

Comment: Yes understood that's the cause, but then in case of some crap | Out-Host, Out-Host still works but we see false because some crap was a wrong command. Why didn't it say true in that case. Why $() subexpression is making a difference.

Comment: `$(nonses that will fail) |Out-Host` <- this resolves to `$null |Out-Host`, which won't fail

Comment: OKay, thank you. Very new to this, will study this further to understand how this. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @SonaliGupta Maybe if you told us a little bit about _why_ you need to add `Out-Host` and `$?` all over the place, we could suggest alternatives? What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Some windows patch that is not supporting powershell with transcription when we are using anything other than powershell cmdlets. Appending Out-Host is just a workaround. Not the best solution but the cleanest at our end. $? is how we figure if our executions passed instead of $LastExitCode because not a clean approach at our end to remove $?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can you elaborate this PowerShell's built-in parser to locate all pipeline expression. any link to using parser?

Answer (score 0):

It's still not entirely clear to me *why* you need to add `Out-Host` all over the place, but the safest option for *programmatically* adding `| Out-Host` to all your pipelines is to parse the existing script using [the `Parser` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```
function Add-TrailingOutHost {
  param(
    [string]$Script
  )

  # Start by parsing the script
  $parserErrors = @()
  $AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($Script, [ref]$null, [ref]$parserErrors)

  if($parserErrors){
    Write-Error 'Errors encountered parsing script'
    return
  }

  # Locate all pipeline expressions in the AST returned by the parser
  $pipelines = $AST.FindAll({
    param($Tree) 

    # We only want "free-standing" pipelines - ignore pipelines in flow control statements and assignments
    $Tree -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.PipelineAst] -and $Tree.Parent -isnot [System.Management.Automation.Language.StatementAst]
  }, $true)

  # We'll be injecting code into the script, thereby modifying the offsets of the existing statements
  # To avoid inject code at the wrong offset we need to traverse the script bottom-up
  for($i = $pipelines.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--){
    $pipeline = $pipelines[$i]

    # Check if the last command in the pipeline is already `Out-*` something - ignore those
    $lastCommand = $pipeline.PipelineElements[-1]
    if($lastCommand.CommandElements[0] -like 'Out-*'){
      continue
    }

    # Otherwise, inject the string `| Out-Host` at the end of the pipeline
    $Script = $Script.Insert($lastCommand.Extent.EndOffset, ' | Out-Host')
  }

  # return modified script
  return $Script
}
```

Now you can add `Out-Host` to the relevant parts of any script with:

```
Add-TrailingOutHost -Script @'
echo "Hello there"

if(Test-Path .){
  echo "Something else"
}
'@
```

The output of which is:

```
echo "Hello there" | Out-Host

if(Test-Path .){
  echo "Something else" | Out-Host
}
```